# Set custom size to custom cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have created a custom cordova plugin and implemented it in an app - all works well. But now i need to make my custom plugin to take specific size and be at specific position in the screen. Everything i tried ONLY resizes the content of the plugin but not the activity itself as that still occupies the full screen - fills the rest of the space with white color. Can someone of you give me some guides on how to achieve this if it is actually possible , or provide some tutorials etc.

What i've tried so far is to alter the android:layout_width & android:layout_height of the root layout but it did not help.

I've also tried to alter LayoutParams from code - still the same issue.

What i would like to expect at the end is to have the custom plugin be positioned on custom position, for example (100, 50), and be of custom size, for example (200, 180)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, the solution was using a fragment instead of an activity. That way by manipulating the margins and the size of the layout of the margin the desired behavior can be achieved.
Taking a look at the source code of this camera plugin really helped a lot.

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview